# Get file from Google Drive and covert to Blob

Tags: javascript, blob, google-drive-api, fileapi

I use function from this Google API JS sample

```
function downloadFile(file, callback) {
  if (file.downloadUrl) {
    var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
 };
 xhr.onerror = function() {
      callback(null);
 };
 xhr.send();
 } else {
    callback(null);
 }
}
```

I get file content, but how i can create Blob from xhr.responseText ?

Comment: I found answer here http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/xhr2/
I had to use
     xhr.responseType='blob'

Comment: If this is the answer, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer here http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/xhr2/

I had to use

```
 xhr.responseType='blob'
```

Comment: I know its quite some years since you posted it... but can you tell me what the file.downloadUrl looked like? a sample

Answer (score 0):

Try to use native [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) constructor.

Example form [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob):

```
var aFileParts = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'];
var oMyBlob = new Blob(aFileParts, {type : 'text/html'}); // the blob
```

Comment: thank you, i try this, but it not work for images. I had to use xhr.responseType='blob'